# Physical meaning of correlation functions, why does obtaining all of them mean solving a given QFT?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, correlation-functions

I vaguely understand that a 2-point function would tell us the propagation from an
exited point to another, but I have no idea what, for any natural number n,
$$\langle\phi(x_1)...\phi(x_n)\rangle=\mathcal{Z}^{-1}\int D\phi e^{-S[\phi]}\phi(x_1)...\phi(x_n)$$
would tell us.

What also confuses me is the statement that obtaining all the correlation functions of a given QFT means solving the system completely. I've learned that these functions are called vacuum expectation values and specify all the fields, but wouldn't one need the whole spectrum and the corresponding probability measure for all observables to claim to have solved the system?
As far as I understand, correlation functions would tell us at best some value in between scattering related to random excitation at n points in spacetime.

Specifically, how would one canonically quantize an observable other than the field operator, or obtain the same results in canonical quantization(e.g. projection valued measure), using the path integral formalism and correlation functions?

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Yeah, computing all the correlation functions (and therefore scattering amplitudes) is not a full solution except perhaps in conformal field theories where there's a state-operator map. But it's still a daunting enough task that if a theory "lets you" do this, it's probably because the theory is "solvable".